# Build para iOS e Android

Tags: android, ios, build

Estou com uma dúvida a respeito do build para o iOS e Android. Recentemente perdi os fontes de um aplicativo que desenvolvi nessas duas plataformas, porém os aplicativos já estão nas lojas. Questionei no suporte da Apple se seria possível programar todo o aplicativo novamente e atualizar a atual versão sem perder o histórico de atualizações, histórico de downloads, comentários, avaliações, etc. Eles não são diretos e a cada e-mail que recebo fico ainda mais confuso se pode ou não. Gostaria de saber para o caso do Android também, pois não sei nem como encontrar essa informação de forma 'oficial'. Se possível, indicar alguma fonte da própria Apple e do Android, por favor - preciso de argumentos na minha empresa

Comment: Cara, só por curiosidade. **Como** tu perdeu o fonte?

Comment: Cara, aqui tinhamos um aplicativo desenvolvido em Xamarim para Android e IOS. Refatoramos as duas plataformas para a linguagem nativa (Java e Swift). O que se deve manter, são o nome do pacote (o que identifica o app na play store), e o Aplicativo deve ser gerado com a mesma chave. Saudações.

Comment: @jbueno Não foi bem eu que perdi os fontes mas estou cuidando disso na empresa. Explicar também seria bem complicado, não foi acidente.

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski, a chave que você fala é o certificado da conta de desenvolvedor usado no XCode para fazer o build?

Comment: exato! Este mesmo

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Existe algum lugar pra usar como fonte? Alguma documentação? Não consegui encontrar. Referente ao Android, funciona assim? Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Não procuramos documentação, apenas refatoramos e subimos! Para o android vc deve manter o mesmo pacote  ex.: **com.example.app** e usar o mesmo .key para gerar o Apk assinado!

Comment: No iOS só usar o mesmo bundle id e a mesma conta de desenvolvedor utilizada no primeiro app.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisará reescrever tudo. Cadastra a mesma conta no Xcode e utilize a mesma bundle ID que a versão que já está na loja. Lembre-se que o número da versão e o número do build precisam ser maiores que a última versão que está lá.

Lembre-se que você não pode remover suporte a um device na versão nova que você escreverá.

Exemplo:
Se seu app tem suporte a iPhone e iPad a nova versão precisará ter suporte a iPhone e iPad. O mesmo vale pra Apple Watch.

Abraço.